# Re-bind jQuery click af AJAX call

Tags: jquery, hoverintent

**UPDATE: I just review my question and I totally get it doesn't make sense. I should not ask questions here when I am tired. It  has now been re-written and with a possible solution**

This is what I want to happen:

1. When the user click a checkbox with the class `filter_products` an AJAX call will be made.
2. An updated list of products will be returned.
3. The updated product list will replace the content in the `UL` with the class `product_list`
   After `product_list` has been updated I want the hoverintent event to re-bind

Code:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <input class="filter_products" type="checkbox" name="product_options[1]" value="1">
    <input class="filter_products" type="checkbox" name="product_options[2]" value="2">
</div>

<div id="main">
    <ul id="product_list">
        <li class="product">
            Product name 1
        </li>
        <li class="product">
            Product name 2
        </li>
    <ul>
</div>

<script>
    // Filter products
    $('.filter_products').on('click', function () {
        var inputs = $("input:checked");
        $.post('/filter_products/' + $('#cat_id').data('cat-id'), inputs.serialize(), function(data) {
            $('#product_list').html(data);
        });
    });

    // Hover product is now wrapped in a function
    $(".product").hoverIntent({over: getAttributtes, out: hideAttributtes});

    function getAttributtes() {
        // Do something
    }

    function hideAttributtes() {
        // Do something
    }
</script>
```

This is probably the solution:

```
// Filter products
$('.filter_products').on('click', function () {
    var inputs = $("input:checked");
    $.post('/filter_products/' + $('#cat_id').data('cat-id'), inputs.serialize(), function(data) {
        $('#product_list').html(data);

        // Re-initialize hoverintent
        hoverAttributtes();
    });
});

// Hover product
function hoverAttributtes() {
    $(".product").hoverIntent({over: getAttributtes, out: hideAttributtes});
}

function getAttributtes() {
    // Do something
}

function hideAttributtes() {
    // Do something
}

// Initialize hoverintent
hoverAttributtes();
```

Comment: You want to rebind which click event handler? I don't see you unbinding anything. Could you describe the whole problem more clearly?

Comment: ... did you miss the part where you were trying to rebind the click event?

Comment: A. What are you trying to do? B. Why are you trying to do that? C. What *isn't* happening that you're expecting to happen? D. What *is* happening that you weren't expecting to happen?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use this click after ajax call then please put this code outside that div which is going to be updated with ajax call.
i mean in main page outside of ajax update.
and there for click use this script.

```
    $(document).on('click','.filter_products', function () {
    var inputs = $("input:checked");
    $.post('/filter_products/' + $('#cat_id').data('cat-id'), inputs.serialize(), function(data) {
        $('#product_list').html(data);
    });
});
```